# Android SDK занимает всё место

Tags: android

При скачивании Android SDK - указан путь сохранения на диск D, но часть места все равно занимается на диске С. Как можно исправить, чтобы заполняло память только на диске D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Даже если папка `android_sdk` хранится на `D:\`, на `C:\` как минимум создается директория `C:\Users\%имя_пользователя%\.android` - в ней хранятся кэши и больше всего места занимают снимки эмулятора в поддиректории `avd`.
Один из вариантов решения: создать симлинк. Перенесите всю папку `.android` на диск `D:`, например `D:\.android`. И в командной строке выполните `mklink /D c:\Users\%имя_пользователя%\.android D:\.android`